# Whats wrong with this replaceAll()?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

The output I get is once the value of `x` is printed and remaining two `println` prints blank lines.

```
1.234.567,89



Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String x = "1.234.567,89 EUR";
        String e = " EUR";
        x = x.replaceAll(" EUR","");
        System.out.println(x);
        x = x.replaceAll(".", "");
        System.out.println(x);
        x = x.replaceAll(",",".");
        System.out.println(x);
           //System.out.println(x.replaceAll(" EUR","").replaceAll(".","").replaceAll(",","."));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `x = x.replaceAll("[.]", "");` The first argument is a regex.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `x = x.replaceAll(".", "");` replaces every character with `""` and therefore you have an empty `x` after the second `replaceAll()`.

Note that the first argument of the `replaceAll()` method is a regular expression.

Change it to:

```
x = x.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

[`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method takes a regex as first parameter. And a `.` in regex matches any character except newline. That is why it is replacing everything.

You can just use [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

```
x = x.replace(" EUR","");
System.out.println(x);
x = x.replace(".", "");
System.out.println(x);
x = x.replace(",",".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(" EUR","").replaceAll("\\.","")
                                                 .replaceAll(",","."));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(" EUR","").replaceAll(".","")
                                                 .replaceAll(",","."));
```

You have to scape `.` with `\\.`

You can do this in single line as follows

```
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(" EUR|\\.|,",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
x = x.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."), "");
```

To tell Java that `.` is **not** the regex `.` that has a special meaning, but the String `.`.

Other solutions:

- Use `replace` that accepts a Strings
- Escape the `.` by `\\.` (Escaping regex is done by `\` but in Java `\` is written `\\`)

Answer (score 0):

Read JavaDoc from [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> **regex**
>
> - the regular expression to which this string is to be matched

[The dot (`.`) matches (almost) any character.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) To escape `dot` use [backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) (`\`), Java needs double backslash (`\\`).

Your fixed code after escaping dot looks like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String x = "1.234.567,89 EUR";
    String e = " EUR";
    x = x.replaceAll(" EUR","");
    System.out.println(x);
    x = x.replaceAll("\\.", "");
    System.out.println(x);
    x = x.replaceAll(",",".");
    System.out.println(x);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution:

Consider to use [NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) or [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). NumberFormat provides a [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method.

E.g. try:

```
final NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
if (currencyFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    final DecimalFormat currencyDecimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) currencyFormat;

    final DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = currencyDecimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol("EUR");
    currencyDecimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);

    currencyDecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

    System.out.println(currencyFormat.format(new BigDecimal("1234567.89")));
    final BigDecimal number = (BigDecimal) currencyFormat.parse("1.234.567,89 EUR");
    System.out.println(number);
}
```